# Inject IAuthorizationFilter using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to inject IAuthorizationFilter with SecurityAuthorizationFilter using Unity  through configuration. I get an exception The type name or alias IAuthorizationFilter could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name. I checked the   types and all of them looks good. Please somebody direct me how can I typically inject the action filters. Thanks in advance

My configuration  as follows

```
  <typeAlias alias="IAuthorizationFilter" type="System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter, System.Web.Mvc"/>
  <typeAlias alias="SecurityAuthorizationFilter" type="JQS.Infrastructure.Security.Filters.SecurityAuthorizationFilter, JQS.Infrastructure.Security"/>



    <register type="IAuthorizationFilter" mapTo="SecurityAuthorizationFilter"/>
```

-George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write full assembly name in type attribute for IAuthorizationFilter alias ( I mean version, culture, public token )